# Font color in string.xml file in Android crashes on older OS

Tags: android

I've created an app in which release is very close.  However, I've found that in older Androids (I know for sure on versions 4.1 and older) the color tag in the strings.xml file causes crashes.  The tag is changing the font to red.

```
<font fgcolor="red">Text goes here</font>
```

There is a lot of text in the app, and some of the strings of red words are embedded in a longer string.  Is there any way to avoid this crash?  I know it works great on Android 4.4 systems...not 100% sure about 4.2 and 4.3.  Any ideas on alternate ways to create red text?  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `HTML` and not `Android` code

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to create red text on a TextView. The implementation should be the same (or very similar) for other views.

You can set the text color programatically in the code:

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
yourTextView.setText("Your text here");
yourTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
```

If you want to set this text color in the XML do so like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:text="Your text here"/>
```

If you want to set your own color instead of using androids pre-defined colors, you can do this by creating a color resource XML file and adding your colors as follows:

```
<resources>
   <color name="red">#FF000000</color>
   <!-- Add other colors here -->
</resources>
```